# It is possible to calculate distance between object to camera without object dimensions?

Tags: opencv, distance, camera-calibration

My goal is to calculate distance from an object that detected based on color.
When given that the camera and the object are horizontal, and also given and real relative height between them.
In the illustration of the problem, only h is known, and the horizontally condition.
Need to find D

[Problem illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBOtR.jpg)

Comment: After computer vision, you get the horizontal angle between camera and object. Tangent of that angle is `(h-H)/D`. If you know `h-H` and the angle, you can calculate `D`.

Comment: If you don't have a stereo vision system then you can calibrate your camera for the known size object and fixed distance and the rest is little math.